# How much is the install size for mgsV Phantom pain?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

so i have a PlayStation 3 super slim with only 12 gigabytes .i want to know what is the install size for disc for metal gear solid V phantom pain for PlayStation 3 because i am getting it for Christmas.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a thread on gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/681794-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72396784):

The digital version requires 11.7 GB (you will need twice the space to download the game), while the physical version requires 6.7 GB.

Comment: And what about dragon ball xenoverse 1, my brother is getting it